# How can I compute a Count Morgan fingerprint as numpy.array?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, scikit-learn, rdkit

I would like to use rdkit to generate count Morgan fingerprints and feed them to a scikit Learn model (in Python). However, I don't know how to generate the fingerprint as a numpy array. When I use

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
m = Chem.MolFromSmiles('c1cccnc1C')
fp = AllChem.GetMorganFingerprint(m, 2, useCounts=True)
```

I get a UIntSparseIntVect that I would need to convert. The only thing I found was cDataStructs (see: http://rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.DataStructs.cDataStructs.html), but this does not currently support UIntSparseIntVect.

Comment: It seems you have to convert the counts by yourself.
You can get the counts with fp.GetNonzeroElements()
`{98513984: 2, 422715066: 1, 951226070: 1, 1100037548: 1, 1207774339: 1, 1235524787: 1, 1751362425: 1, 2041434490: 1, 2246728737: 1, 2614860224: 1, 3217380708: 1, 3218693969: 4, 3776905034: 1, 3999906991: 1, 4036277955: 1, 4048591891: 1}`

Comment: I saw that but how would I fold that to a fp of reasonable size, like 1024 digits?

Comment: `fp = AllChem.GetHashedMorganFingerprint(m, 2, nBits=1024)`
Or do you want the bits (0 and 1)?
`fp = AllChem.GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(m, 2, nBits=1024)`
This could be converted to an array with DataStructs

Comment: Yes, I want to use counts. `GetHashedMorganFingerprint` looks very good, I could not find this before. However, it creates a UIntSparseIntVect again, so DataStructs does not work. Any better option than to do: `fp_dict = fp.GetNonZeroElements()`and then loop over fp_dict.items() like so: `for key, val in fp_dict.items():
    fp_arr[key] = val` ??

Comment: What about this `fp_arr = np.array(list(fp_dict.items()))` ?

Comment: No, given `dict = {1:2, 3:4}` and the fp would be 5 bit long, I would want `[0,2,0,4,0]` . Your solution gives `[[1,2],[3,4]]` (Sorry, I do not have rdkit installed on this machine.) Guess I will just go with the loop. May I write the answer or do you want to?

Comment: Because the question is about creating an array, it's your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe a little late to answer but these methods work for me

If you want the bits (0 and 1):

```
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
from rdkit.Chem import DataStructs

mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('c1cccnc1C')
fp = AllChem.GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(mol, 2, nBits=1024)
array = np.zeros((0, ), dtype=np.int8)
DataStructs.ConvertToNumpyArray(fp, array)
```

And back to a fingerprint:

```
bitstring = "".join(array.astype(str))
fp2 = DataStructs.cDataStructs.CreateFromBitString(bitstring)
assert list(fp.GetOnBits()) == list(fp2.GetOnBits())
```

If you want the counts:

```
fp3 = AllChem.GetHashedMorganFingerprint(mol, 2, nBits=1024)
array = np.zeros((0,), dtype=np.int8)
DataStructs.ConvertToNumpyArray(fp3, array)
print(array.nonzero())
```

Output:

```
(array([ 19,  33,  64, 131, 175, 179, 356, 378, 428, 448, 698, 707, 726,
   842, 849, 889]),)
```

And back to a fingerprint (Not sure this is the best way to do this):

```
def numpy_2_fp(array):
    fp = DataStructs.cDataStructs.UIntSparseIntVect(len(array))
    for ix, value in enumerate(array):
        fp[ix] = int(value)
    return fp

fp4 = numpy_2_fp(array)
assert fp3.GetNonzeroElements() == fp4.GetNonzeroElements()
```

Comment: `DataStructs.ConvertToNumpyArray(fp3, array)` returns a NoneType.

Comment: Yes, the array is populated in place

Comment: Oh, yeah, my bad, it's in place. 
I'm startled right now. This is so obvious. I was absolutely sure this did not work, but obviously it does. 
Btw: Why did you use `np.zeros()` for the bit-case and `np.array()` for the count-case?

Comment: My mistake, I think both should probably be `np.zeros()`

Answer (score 1):

```
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
m = Chem.MolFromSmiles('c1cccnc1C')
fp = AllChem.GetHashedMorganFingerprint(m, 2, nBits=1024)
fp_dict = fp.GetNonZeroElements()
arr = np.zeros((1024,))
for key, val in fp_dict.items():
    arr[key] = val
```

It seems there is no direct way to get a numpy array so I build it from the dictionary.

Comment: AttributeError: 'UIntSparseIntVect' object has no attribute 'GetNonZeroElements' is what I get when I try to run this